# Entity Framework Core 2.0 - Add-Migration não funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, migrations, entity-framework-core

Estou criando um novo projeto code-first. Ao tentar criar o migration, usando o comando `[Add-Migration Initial -Context LogAuditoriaContext]` ele simplesmente não faz nada, não cria, não dá erro, não informa nada:

Já tentei mapear com `FluentAPI` tanto no `OnModelCreating()` quanto em arquivos separados, o resultado é o mesmo.

Olhando para a Janela de Saída, mostra:

> Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped

Estou usando dot.net core 2.0 e C# 7.2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**UPDATE (Solução)**
Com as dicas do @Armindo Gomes, consegui descobri que o problema era a string de conexão, bastou apenas trocar o nome de `LogAuditoria` para `LogAuditoriaConnection` e as suas referências em Startup e no `LogAuditoriaContext`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já rodou o  Enable-Migrations ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, o Enable-Migrations está obsoleto no entity framework core. Agora usa-se o Add-Migration

Comment: acho, é bem acho mesmo, tem uma linha verde pontilhada no json de configuração na chave `LogAuditoria` acho que está faltando uma barra `Desktop\SqlExpress` deveria ser `Desktop\\SqlExpress` faz o teste!

Comment: @LeoFelipe, verdade, não tinha visto que era core shausa... der um Clean  solution e compile novamente.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, vlw pela dica, realmente deveria estar com duas barras mesmo. mas, infelizmente, não foi o caso de resolver, mas muito obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: @Marconcilio Souza, já havia feito o clean e rebuild, porém sem sucesso.

Comment: @LeoFelipe, já tentou seguindo os passos https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?

Comment: poderia enviar o log detalhado do VS? https://elbruno.com/2015/01/06/vs2015-howto-show-more-detail-in-a-local-build-in-the-visual-studio-ide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

No arquivo *appsettings.json*

```
"LogAuditoriaConnection": "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=LogAuditoria;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=sa;Password=**********"
```

No arquivo *LogAuditoriaContext.cs*

```
public class LogAuditoriaContext : DbContext {

    public LogAuditoriaContext(DbContextOptions<LogAuditoriaContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<LogLocation> LogLocation{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogRequest> LogRequest { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogResponse> LogResponse { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sistema> Sistema { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

No arquivo *Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddDbContext<LogAuditoriaContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogAuditoriaConnection")));
    // Outros services
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Na console do *PMC*:

```
add-migration NomeMigration
update-database
```

Fonte:

[Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with a New database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db)

Comment: obrigado. Descobri que o problema era a string de conexão, bastou apenas trocar o nome de LogAuditoria para LogAuditoriaConnection e as suas refeências em Startup e no LogAuditoriaContext. Muito obrigado!